# Text not being wrapped automatically using android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout

Tags: android, grid-layout

I am designing a layout using android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout but I'm facing one issue, the text is not being wrapped automatically.

Here is the xml layout file and screen shot of that layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mcd_rlMainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mcd_rlBgContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mcd_ivBg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/simple_bg" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/internal_margin" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mcd_rlTopBarBgContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:background="@drawable/select_language_top_bg" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_ivBack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/back" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvHeading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@string/temp_circle_detail"
                    android:textColor="@color/un_selected"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mcd_rlTopBarBgContainer"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
                app:columnCount="8"
                app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                app:useDefaultMargins="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_ivCircleImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_photo"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_photo"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="4"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="4"
                    app:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_stub" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="4" />

                <!-- First name -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvFirstNameKey"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/temp_first_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/selected"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvFirstNameValue"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/temp_first_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/un_selected" />

                <!-- Last Name -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvLastNameKey"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/temp_last_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/selected"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvLastNameValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/temp_last_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/un_selected" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="4" />
                <!-- Date Of Birth -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvDateOfBirthKey"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="3"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/temp_dateofbirth"
                    android:textColor="@color/selected"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvDateOfBirthValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="5"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/temp_dateofbirth"
                    android:textColor="@color/un_selected" />

                <!-- Gender -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvGenderKey"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="3"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/temp_gender"
                    android:textColor="@color/selected"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvGenderValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="5"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/temp_gender"
                    android:textColor="@color/un_selected" />

                <!-- Address -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvAddressKey"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/temp_address"
                    android:textColor="@color/selected"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvAddressValue"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="6"
                    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="@string/temp_address"
                    android:textColor="@color/un_selected" />

                <!-- Thread Listing -->

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="8"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvThread1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="8"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="Thread-1"
                    android:textColor="@color/un_selected"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvThread1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="8"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="Thread-2"
                    android:textColor="@color/un_selected"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvThread1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="8"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="Thread-3"
                    android:textColor="@color/un_selected"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mcd_tvThread1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="8"
                    app:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="Thread-4"
                    android:textColor="@color/un_selected"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue. I have tried using  android:layout_width="0dip" and app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" but that also does not solve the problem.

I really appreciate for any help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: After searching a lot, finally i found the solution that we have to use below propery :

android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot, finally i found the solution that we have to use below property : android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"